# looping in Puppet 5 results in duplicate declaration error

Tags: puppet

Request some help please.

Requirement is to create a custom firewall service and then allow this custom firewall service only to a selected ips (trying to use firewalld_rich_rules here).

Here is the sample code:

```
class foo::fwall (
$sourceip = undef,
)
{
  include firewalld

  if $sourceip {
    $sourceip.each |String $ipaddr| {
      firewalld_rich_rule { "rich_rule_${ipaddr}":
        ensure      => enabled,
        permanent   => true,
        zone        => 'public',
        family      => ipv4,
        source      => $ipaddr,
        element     => service,
        servicename => 'bar',
        action      => accept,
      }
    }
  }

  # this is defined in firewalld class and works good
  firewalld::custom_service { 'bar':
    short       => 'bar custom service',
    description => 'custom service ports',
    ports       => [
      {
        port     => '7771',
        protocol => 'tcp',
      },
      {
        port     => '8282',
        protocol => 'tcp',
      },
      {
        port     => '8539',
        protocol => 'tcp',
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

and while running it on a node, with couple of ip addresses (provided as an array for $sourceip), it results in duplicate declaration error

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Duplicate declaration: Firewalld_rich_rule[rich_rule_2] is already declared at (file: .../dev/modules/test/manifests/fwall.pp, line: 11); cannot redeclare (file: .../dev/modules/test/manifests/fwall.pp, line: 11) (file: .../dev/modules/test/manifests/fwall.pp, line: 11, column: 7) on node server.domain
```

Trying it in puppet v5.5 (from puppetlabs) for Redhat Enterprise Linux 7 servers

Note: tried defining a resource following this example from Puppet documentation but getting invalid address error.

```
define puppet::binary::symlink ($binary = $title) {
  file {"/usr/bin/${binary}":
    ensure => link,
    target => "/opt/puppetlabs/bin/${binary}",
  }
}

Use the defined type for the iteration somewhere ele in your manifest file:

$binaries = ['facter', 'hiera', 'mco', 'puppet', 'puppetserver']

puppet::binary::symlink { $binaries: }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the datatype for $sourceip to array in RH Satellite's smart class parameters which was String by default. Everything works good now.

Comment: It's a very good practice to declare your class parameters' data types in the class definition.  Doing so in this case might have helped Satellite get it right in the first place, but even if it didn't, it would have at least yielded a more helpful error message.